# Need help on organizing a multi-module in Kotlin dsl Gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In my previous multi-module projects, I used to do below for organizing common dependencies and whatnot

```
top level
----------
plugins {
//    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
//    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
//    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

apply from: 'config.gradle'

config.gradle
--------------
subprojects { Project module ->
    if (module.name == 'app') {
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    } else {
        apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
    }
    //apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
    apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
    apply from: './jacoco.gradle'
    android { ..}
    dependencies {}
}
app.gradle 
-----------
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
```

This worked fine,
Now I have started migrating to Kotlin Gradle and below is what I have

```
top-lvel
--------
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.10" apply false
    // ksp thingy
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.10-1.0.13" apply false
}
app.gradle 
-----------
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
}
```

And, to above, what I tried

```
top-lvel
--------
plugins {
    // id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
    // id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.10" apply false
    // ksp thingy
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.10-1.0.13" apply false
}
apply from: 'config.gradle'
app.gradle 
-----------
plugins {
    // id("com.android.application")
    // id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    // id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
}


config.gradle
---------------
subprojects { ->

    if (this.name == "app") {
        apply(plugin = "com.android.application")
    } else {
        apply(plugin = "com.android.library")
    }

    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    apply(plugin = "com.google.devtools.ksp")
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.dokka")


    dependencies {
    // todo - common for all subprojects
    }
}
```

But It seems I am doing something wrong as gradle sync gets failed highlighting "Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found."

I used to do this before migrating which worked but not sure now.

A bit of a guide would be helpful here!